# Stopping scroll in iOS hybrid app

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

How do I stop scroll in background which has a overlay/pop up on it? I have disabled the scroll and its working fine on windows and android but the background scrolls in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no direct way or a Windows Store app to launch other apps. The only way is to launch files or URIs into the default handlers for those file types and protocols.

If this is a side-loaded enterprise app then it can use a brokered Windows Runtime Component to call desktop code, and that desktop code can then call desktop API to launch other apps. See [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx)